# How to keep selected value after submit in php

Tags: php

Below is the code where only two options are there in dropdown list i.e. 2016 and 2017. I want to keep selected value after submit. But i m getting 2016 after selecting 2017. What changes need to be done?

```
<?php
$yearArray = range(2016, 2017);
?>

<select name="year" id="select2">
<option value="0">Select Year</option>
<?php
foreach ($yearArray as $year)
{

    $selected = ( $year == 2016) ? 'selected' : '';
    echo '<option name="year" '.$selected.'  value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: What do you mean by submit? You are submitted the form about change the select box?

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar yes i am submitting form. and i want to keep selected option in selectbox after hitting submit button.

Comment: Can you upload your full file content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why 2016 is selected always is because you are setting it to 2016.

```
<?php
foreach ($yearArray as $year)
{

    $selected = ( $year == 2016) ? 'selected' : ''; // Here, you are setting it 
    echo '<option name="year" '.$selected.'  value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';
}
?>
```

Instead do this,

```
<?php
foreach ($yearArray as $year)
{

    $selected = ((isset($_POST['year']) && $_POST['year'] == $year) || ($year == '2016')) ? 'selected' : '';

    echo '<option name="year" '.$selected.'  value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';
}
?>
```

By default 2016 is selected, if you have submitted any other value, that will be selected.

Comment: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: Sorry, there has been typo. Fixed it now.

Comment: M getting "select year" after submitting form which is default

Comment: Okay, Now I've made 2016 as default. Kindly check updated answer

Comment: I have made it like if there is submitted value take that, else if year = 2016 then keep that as selected

Comment: thnku bro ... i used == instead of === and it worked for me... please edit ur answer so that i will close and accept it.

Comment: $selected = (isset($_POST['year']) && $_POST['year'] == $year) ? 'selected' : '';

Comment: I just did. Modified from === to == :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if((isset($_POST['year']) && $year == $_POST['year'])){
    $selected = 'selected';
 }else if($year == 2016){
   $selected = 'selected';
}
```