# php - How to keep select values after search click

Tags: javascript, php, select, drop-down-menu

I have a select tag that helps the user filter search results by years. I wish to keep the value of the selected option after clicking on 'search'.
I use php but for the select options I used JS:

```
var minA = new Date().getFullYear(),
    maxA = 1900,
    selectA = document.getElementById('selesctDatesOne');

for (var i = maxA; i<=minA; i++){
    var optA = document.createElement('option');
    optA.value = i;
    optA.innerHTML = i;
    selectA.appendChild(optA);
}
```

This is the html:

```
<select name="yearsFrom" id="selesctDatesOne" ></select>
```

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819756/how-to-keep-selected-value-after-submit-in-php) but I can't figure out how to use it since I set the options via JS.
any idea how to approach this?

Comment: You want o get the value from back end using php?

Comment: So set `optA.selected` to true or false then, when creating your options?

Comment: Are you asking how to persist the selection after a postback and refresh?

Comment: @ADyson - yes. possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. For example php could echo the selected option back into the page into JS variable assignmen, and then run some JS to update the UI based on that, as soon as the page has loaded.